How to view Laravel + Inertia + Vue3 App on Mobile Device
I'm developing an app on mac and am attempting to test on mobile, but it's not allowing me to view the pages on my mobile device.
I've already attempted to use php artisan serve --host=LOCAL_IP --port=8000 
After I run that command, the page loads on the mobile device and I see the Laravel Debugbar I've installed, but the actual view doesn't load.
Any idea what I need to do to get this working?

Somehow the vite hot module reload server isn't working when accessing from an external device.
What I did was explicit set the internal IP address on hmr host property on vite.config.js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import ip from 'ip'
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    hmr: {
      // Set the ip only if you're using "--host" flag via cli
      // or the server won't work on your local machine,
      // you'll be forced to use --host every time.
      host: process.argv.includes('--host') ? ip.address() : null
    }
  },
})

Now you can just run npm run dev -- --host and you should be able to access your app from another device, using the address showing on terminal, but with the port where Laravel is running (instead of 5173, the Laravel port, usually 8000)
Obs.: You still need to expose the host when running Laravel server, like php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
